# Spliting a 3D numpy array on desired axis

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a NumPy array of shape (4809, 200, 31) and i want to extract following array out of it : shape (4809, 200, 1). so I want to extract one column from axis=2 from the source array which will have three-axis (0,1,2).

Comment: Are you looking for `A[:,:,0:1]`? This will have a shape of `(4809, 200, 1)`. It would help if you made a toy example (with less data) of what you have and what you want.

Comment: yes @Mark that is correct. I exactly need A[:,:,0:1]. That was easier than I thought. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple as doing

A[:,:,0:1].
Thanks @Mark for the answer.